# How to get a tag value to change my URL

Tags: javascript

How can i get a choosen tag value to change my URL? The code works fine but only the choosen tag values are missing. I think my mistake is the "+textbox.value" but i've no idea how to handel that.

```
 <body>
  <label for="tags">Titel: </label>
<input type="text" id="tags" onchange="adjustLink();" />
<a href="#" id="filterLink">Filtern</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function adjustLink() {
  var link = document.getElementById("filterLink");
  var textbox = document.getElementById("tags");
  link.href = "AllItems.aspx?FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=" + textbox.value;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: For one thing, you are doing `var textbox = document.getElementById("tags").value` then `textbox.value`. This is equivalent to `document.getElementById("tags").value.value`

Comment: `document.write` is a function you should be calling, not a variable you should be assigning. What are you trying to do on that line?

Comment: Just change `textbox.value` to `textBox` because you already get the value earlier. Also change `document.write = (textbox);` to `document.write(textbox);`.

Comment: You should open the Javascript console and look for errors there before posting here.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code. Now you can see the code which i meant. And sorry for be so desperate that i not checked the javascript console earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `textbox` variable contains the value of the input, not the input element. So there is nothing like `textbox.value`. So you can directly use like this

```
link.href = "AllItems.aspx?FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=" + textbox
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7Bsp/)

Comment: I tested your solution but it won't work. it's the same problem like before

Comment: @Tiac its working as expected and I have added a fiddle example. Please look into this and let me know for any query